# Using the sum function in GAMS to sum over a subset of variables

Tags: sum, gams-math

I am working with maximazation problems in GAMS where I will choose 
`X=(x_1,x2,...,x_n)` such that `f(X)=c_1*x_1+...c_n*x_n` is maximized. The c's are known scalars and I know `n` (10 in my case). I want my constraints to be such that the first `(n-1)=9` x's should sum up to one and the last one should be less than 10. **How do I use the sum to do so?**

This is what I have tried:

```
SET C / c1 .... c2 /;
ALIAS(Assets,i)

Parameter Valuesforc(i) 'C values'/
*( here are my values typed in for all the C1)

POSITIVE VARIABLES
    x(i);

EQUATIONS
    Const1 First constraint
    Const1 Second constraint
    Obj    The Object;
* here comes the trouble:
Const1 ..   x(10) =l= 10
Const2 ..   sum((i-1),x(i)) =e= 1
```

The code is not done all the way but I believe the essential setup is typed in. **How do you make the summation to find `x_1+x_1 + .... x_(n-1)` and how do you refer to `x_10`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Const1 ..   x('10') =l= 10;
Const2 ..   sum(i$(ord(i)<card(i)),x(i)) =e= 1;
```

Edit: Here are some notes to explain what happens in Const2, especially in the "$(ord(i) < card(i))" part.

- The "$" starts a condition, so it excludes certain elements of i from the sum (see: https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_CondExpr.html#UG_CondExpr_TheDollarCondition)
- The operator ord returns the relative position of a member in a set (see: https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_OrderedSets.html#UG_OrderedSets_TheOrdOperator)
- The operator card returns the number of elements in a set (see: https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_OrderedSets.html#UG_OrderedSets_TheCardOperator)

So, all in all, there is a condition saying that all elements of i should be included in the sum except for the last one.

Comment: Thanks. This will probably solve my problem. Will you please ad some words on why constraint 2 looks they way it does? Why will `$` sign work in this case?

Comment: I added some comments to my post. Hope, that helps.